# Transforming short repeated words in columns into numbers

Tags: text-processing, terminal

I want to transform the short repeated words in columns into numbers.

In the following example I want to change the words `(with ONLY 2 LETTERS)` in column 3 for numbers, so that `AA` is changed to `2`, `AB` or `BA` into `1`, `BB` into `0`.

The first and second column may also contain `AA`, `BB`, `AB` and `BA`. These should not be changed.

Columns are separated by `" "` ().

```
Id_animal Id_SNP Allele
ID01 rs01 AB
ID02 rs01 BA
ID03 rs01 AA
ID04 rs01 BB
```

The wanted output is:

```
Id_animal Id_SNP Allele
ID01 rs01 1
ID02 rs01 1
ID03 rs01 2
ID04 rs01 0
```

Comment: I tried : `perl -F" " -alne 'print join " ", @F[0], map { tr/AA/BA/AB/BB/2/1/1/0/; $_ } @F[1]' input` .         
The same command, but all together `perl -F" " -alne 'print join " ", @F[0], map { tr/AABAABBB/2110/; $_ } @F[1]' input` <br/> `

Comment: do add that to question detail and output/error for that

Comment: `tr` is suitable for one-to-one **single** character mapping.. so not a choice in this case...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
sed -i.bak -r 's/ AA$/ 2/;s/ (AB|BA)$/ 1/;s/ BB$/ 0/' input
```

- `-i.bak` in place editing and create a backup of original file as `input.bak`
- `-r` extended regex syntax
- `s/ AA$/ 2/` replace ending character sequence of ' AA' with 2
- `(AB|BA)` either AB or BA
- `;` separates the different substitute operations

Answer (score 6):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {                                     
        t["AA"] = 2
        t["AB"] = t["BA"] = 1
        t["BB"] = 0
    }       
    $3 ~ /^[AB][AB]$/ { $3 = t[$3] }
    1' data.txt
```

Comment: The lookup table is an interesting idea. I was crafting a far more ornate ``awk`` solution (I was actually having awk calculate the number of ``A``s), but I like this quite a bit better. I might recommend matching on the third field of a line though instead of matching not-the-first line: ``$3 ~ /^[AB][AB]$/ …``

Answer (score 5):

If you want to pursue your attempted perl solution, one way would be to use a *hash* as a simple lookup table e.g.

```
%table = ("AA" => 2,"AB" => 1,"BA" => 1,"BB" => 0)
```

and then use the value of `@F[2]` as the key. So for example

```
perl -alne '
  %table = ("AA" => 2,"AB" => 1,"BA" => 1,"BB" => 0); 
  print $.==1? $_ : join " ", @F[0,1], $table{@F[2]}
' file
Id_animal Id_SNP Allele
ID01 rs01 1
ID02 rs01 1
ID03 rs01 2
ID04 rs01 0
```

---

Actually though there *is* a way to do the simple case you described using perl's `tr` - since it returns the number of transliterations.Hence you can just use the return value of `tr /A//` to count the number of As:

```
perl -alne 'print $.==1? $_ : join " ", @F[0,1], @F[2] =~ tr/A//' file
Id_animal Id_SNP Allele
ID01 rs01 1
ID02 rs01 1
ID03 rs01 2
ID04 rs01 0
```

or even simpler (using a regex to identify the target string, instead of splitting and joining)

```
perl -pe 's/\b[AB]{2}\b/$& =~ tr{A}{}/ge' file
```

You could use the same trick with `awk` i.e.

```
awk 'FNR>1 {$3 = gsub(/A/,"",$3)}1' file
```